# What is the name of these images style?

Tags: style

I am trying to find similar stock images, but not sure what would be the name of this style, to properly search (similar to clipart, illustration, etc...)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: These are renders, not even photos, so technically off-topic. But somebody with experience should be able to help.

Comment: CGI... the replacement for product photography...

Comment: Search for *car render* (maybe replace *car* by the brand or model you are looking for). Some stock photography websites allow you to filter results to only contain renders although the categorization is not always appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretending that the car images are photographs (they're not – they're photorealistic renders, as noted in the comments to the question), you could add some technical terms to hopefully improve your search.

The images present **three-quarters** (or possibly **two-thirds**) **perspective** projection view. Note that 3/4 (or 2/3) is not referring to the aspect ratio of the image. The term comes from portraiture, where approximately 3/4 (or 2/3) of the model's face is visible in the portrait. From the [portrait painting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portrait_painting#three-quarter_view) Wikipedia article:

[image: Sir Anthony Van Dyck - Charles I (1600-49)]
<sub>*Charles I (1600-49)*, by Sir Anthony Van Dyck. Public domain via [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Sir_Anthony_Van_Dyck_-_Charles_I_(1600-49)_-_Google_Art_Project.jpg)</sub>

This painting depcits the subject in profile, full face, and three-quarters views. Profile could be considered "one half" view, because only half the face is visible.

See also: [What is a "3/4" picture and what makes it 3/4?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/75199/11924)